# c++ stl sort segmentation fault on vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

I recently encountering a pretty weird c++ STL sort behavior when I tried to apply a greater than compare function sort on a vector of strings, the detailed implementation could be found below:

```
//Compare the modify time of two files                                                                                                                                          
bool cmp_modifytime(const base::String &file1, const base::String &file2)
{   
    struct stat statbuf1, statbuf2;
    stat(file1.getBuffer(), &statbuf1);
    stat(file2.getBuffer(), &statbuf2);
    return statbuf1.st_mtime > statbuf2.st_mtime;
}
```

main routine:

```
std::vector<base::String> lFiles;
getFilesFromDir(dir, lFiles);
int fileCount = lFiles.size();
for(int i = 0; i <fileCount; i++)
{
    tmp_str = dir;
    tmp_str.append("/");
    tmp_str.append(lFiles[i]);
    lFiles[i] = tmp_str;
}
sort(lFiles.begin(), lFiles.end(), cmp_modifytime);
```

When I decode the crash, the backtrace looks like the following:

```
#0  0xf49a8940 in typeinfo for base::AString () from xxx
#1  0xf4919262 in cmp_modifytime (file1=..., file2=...) at xxx
#2  0xf491f91a in std::__unguarded_partition<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<base::String*, std::vector<base::String> >, base::String, bool (*)(base::String const&, base::String const&)> (__first=..., __last=..., __pivot=..., __comp=0xf491923b <cmp_modifytime(base::String const&, base::String const&)>)
at xxx
#3  0xf491e5da in std::__unguarded_partition_pivot<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<base::String*, std::vector<base::String> >, bool (*)(base::String const&, base::String const&)>
(__first=..., __last=..., __comp=0xf491923b <cmp_modifytime(base::String const&, base::String const&)>)
at xxx
#4  0xf491d0cc in std::__introsort_loop<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<base::String*, std::vector<base::String> >, int, bool (*)(base::String const&, base::String const&)> (
__first=..., __last=..., __depth_limit=7, __comp=0xf491923b <cmp_modifytime(base::String const&, base::String const&)>)
at xxx
#5  0xf491d0ef in std::__introsort_loop<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<base::String*, std::vector<base::String> >, int, bool (*)(base::String const&, base::String const&)> (
__first=..., __last=..., __depth_limit=8, __comp=0xf491923b <cmp_modifytime(base::String const&, base::String const&)>)
at xxx
#6  0xf491d0ef in std::__introsort_loop<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<base::String*, std::vector<base::String> >, int, bool (*)(base::String const&, base::String const&)> (
__first=..., __last=..., __depth_limit=9, __comp=0xf491923b <cmp_modifytime(base::String const&, base::String const&)>)
at xxx
#7  0xf491c198 in std::sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<base::String*, std::vector<base::String> >, bool (*)(base::String const&, base::String const&)> (__first=..., 
__last=..., __comp=0xf491923b <cmp_modifytime(base::String const&, base::String const&)>)
at xxx
#8  0xf4919521 in main routine
```

The crash happened in the compare function, and interestingly I found that one of the input String object is an empty string:

```
(gdb) p file1
$1 = (const base::String &) @0x11db6180: {<base::Object> = {_vptr.Object = 0xf49a88e8}, <base::AString> = {_vptr.AString = 0xf49a8908}, buffer = 0x0, hashValue = 4294967295, size = -1, immutable = false}
(gdb) p file2
$2 = (const base::String &) @0x11db5f58: {<base::Object> = {_vptr.Object = 0xf49a8888}, <base::AString> = {_vptr.AString = 0xf49a88c8}, buffer = 0x11db6ba8 "testString123", hashValue = 4294967295, size = 13, immutable = false}
(gdb) p &file2
$3 = (const base::String *) 0x11db5f58
(gdb) p &file1
$4 = (const base::String *) 0x11db6180
```

And what's more interesting is that this empty string address is the same as the _M_finish of the vector I tried to do the sort, which means somehow sort takes the vector.end() into the compare function:

```
(gdb) p lFiles._M_impl._M_finish
$7 = (std::allocator<base::String>::pointer) 0x11db6180
```

This should never happen in my understanding.

Comment: Hard to say for sure without an [mcve], but could be that you haven't implemented copy/assignment of `base::String` properly.

Comment: In particular, swapping/assigning `base::String` must also preserve the original `st_mtime`. If those get modified in any way while the algorithm is running, the preconditions of `std::sort` are violated.

Comment: What does `getBuffer()` return?

Comment: You should be looking into `base::String` and its implementation more so than `std::sort`.  All `sort` (and `std::vector`) did was more than likely exposed one or more bugs in the `String`'s copy semantics.